# Como valido un input de formulario que solo ingresen hasta 2 palabras en javascript?

Tags: validación, input

```js
const spl3 = nombre.value.split(' ');
const nombreConTrim = nombre.value.trim('');

if (!(nombreConTrim == true || spl3.length > 1)) {
  error = true;
  alert('Debe ingresar solo 2 palabras');
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Una pregunta que sólo muestra código sin ningún contexto adicional, no suele ser bien recibida. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta para añadirle más información sobre el problema, el resultado esperado y el comportamiento actual. Puedes leer [mcve] para que tengas una idea. Saludos

Comment: Y cuál es el problema con el código que incluyes?

Comment: no me validaba el ingresar mas de 2 strings, gracias ya lo resolvi, sdos!

Comment: @ArcangelDark Deberías de editar tu pregunta y añadir **el problema en especifico que tienes**.

Answer (score 0):

```
const spl3 = nombre.value.split(' ') //Separamos el valor por espacios
            .filter(function(n) { return n != '' }) //Ignoramos los resultados que no contengan nada
            .length;//Cogemos la logintud del array resultante del split

if (spl3 > 2) { //Si la longitud es superior a 2, muestras la alerta
  error = true;
  alert('Debe ingresar solo 2 palabras');
}
```

Comment: gracias!, me ayudo mucho!

Answer (score 0):

```
const spl3 = nombre.value
            .trim() // primero hacer un trim()
            .replace(/\s+/, ' ') // remover espacios consecutivos dentro del string
            .split(' '); // luego el split

// la condición debe ser mayor que 2 ya que la longitud del arreglo
// inicia en 1
if (spl3.length > 2) {
  error = true;
  alert('Debe ingresar solo 2 palabras');
}
```

Comment: gracias!!, me sirvio a resolverlo!